# Hide or remove comments box from wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin everything is going fine but there is a problem.
How can I hide or remove the comments box? I lost many hours but could not develop the right script.  My current script is this:

```
add_filter( 'comments_template', 'remove_comments_template_on_pages', 11 );
function remove_comments_template_on_pages( $file ) {
     if ( is_page() ) 
        comments_template('', true);
}
```

I don't know how to develop this script. Any help could lead me to complete my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to you **functions.php** file.

```
add_action('init', 'remove_page_feature');

function remove_page_feature() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'comments' );
}
```

And now provide a check before the comments template is executed, as below:

```
if ( post_type_supports( 'page', 'comments' );  )
    comments_template('', true);
}
```

**Note: Using the above code will disable *comments* on pages.**